# React-native .env files are not working properly

Tags: react-native

I followed the guide and I used react-native-dotenv lib.

Here is my babel.co

```
 module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    'module:react-native-dotenv',
  ],
};
```

Here is what I have in my .env file:

```
URL="someUrl"
```

And this is how I'm trying to use it:

```
import {URL} from 'react-native-dotenv';
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
   Unknown option: .name. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

Any solutions on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation tells you to import it via:

```
import {URL} from '@env'
```

and not

```
import {URL} from 'react-native-dotenv';
```

Comment: how can I fix it ?

Comment: dotenv is no longer a preset but a plugin. 

replace your babel:
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [['module:react-native-dotenv']],
};